# Google maps API , reverse geocoder not return the full address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding, geocode

Im using google maps api to return formatted address for given location, but the result is very basic. I use the code from the [Reverse Geocoding example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)
With these coordinates ( 43.850429, 25.952279) return "Русе център, Русе, България".
When i just click on the map in google.com/maps show "улица „Църковна независимост“ 9, 7000 Русе България" which is the full address. 
How to get the full address, this from google maps or from street view?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infowindow in the example shows the `formatted_address` for the 2nd result, use the first result:

```
infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
```